# ask for some references for embedded telecom board

Tags: embedded, telecommunication

I am involved with an embedded software development for telecom industry. I have zero experience before with such embedded hardware devices.

I got a network processor board, which is featured in switching pipeline engines. 
Besides the board, there is also an accessory board called "piggy"(seems for ethernet connetion), and another serial line connection.

I am completely lost about these boards and serial line connections. what they are used for? I tried to use google to find some useful introduction or materials but failed. Can anyone point out what this piggy board is used for? Any good references or books that explain about this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing how did you ever get this job!?  And why does the hardware you have been provided with have no documentation? That is not how the "telecom industry" works!  The hardware is most likly custom boards designed for a specific project or system rather than a general purpose publically documented platform.

Comment: HI, Clifford, thanks for your reply. I am quite new to this position. And definitely these is some specific document about this board. However, what I am asking for is to have some generic materials, maybe embedded hardware introduction. It is like you take a generic Operating System or Dragon book, but you have to work with linux or gcc compiler. So some concrete information would be appreciated, like the relation of piggy board and the main board, etc.

Comment: The point is the tern "piggy board" is entirely proprietary, so the question cannot be answered.  No doubt it is called that simply because it 'piggy-backs' on to the main board.  This type of connection is often called a "mezzanine board", but knowing that will not help you program it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop for your embedded system you will need a development host (a PC or workstation that hosts the development tools including cross-compiler, platform libraries, debugger etc.), and a debug connection to the target (typically an in-circuit emulator or JTAG debugger, but in some cases debug over serial, USB or Ethernet may be supported via software running on the target - though that is less reliable since the code you are debugging may corrupt or break the debug stub running on the same target).

When you have got that together and can build, load and run code on the target, you may then be in a position to ask a more specific question.  Writing code for this platform will depend on many things such as processor type, programming language, target operating system (if any), real-time performance requirements, regulatory standards, product type standards etc.

With respect to how to access your specific hardware, then no one can tell you that without access to the documentation and hardware schematics, and you cannot do anything with it yourself without that.  Some knowledge of electronics will be a distinct advantage in most cases.